# About License under software manager

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, licenses, software-distribution

[image]

I use linux mint 21.3 Cinnamon Edition. I see in the software manager under licence,  where it say changing is not allowed. what is the meaning of it? Please tell me.  **(Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies of this license document, but changing it is not allowed.)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is about the text of the license ([GPL v3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html)) itself, not the software. It means that while [the FSF](https://www.fsf.org/) allows you to use the GPL license for your projects (which often involves copying the text of the license when you distribute the software), you *cannot* modify **the text of the license itself**. The license itself is owned by the FSF and they do not give anyone the right to modify it. You are free to modify the software, of course, as long as you obey the GPL when redistributing your changes.

Comment: That means I can change the options and and settings of  installed software or browser.

Comment: Oh, yes. The GPL gives you complete freedom to *use the software* however you want.

Comment: one more question , is there any sign up option in software manager?

Comment: @Md.SobrulIslam I don't know, I don't use it.